# How to sync clock and UIDs across different nodes of a cluster with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cluster

I am new to cluster computing and Ubuntu. We have a computing cluster with 4 nodes (10 cores per node) with Ubuntu installed. The cluster is meant for scientific computing. To install a load management system first I need to sync UIDs and clock across all nodes. I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the clock part, look at ntp. All the clocks  will be maintain synchronized from the net.

For the UID part, I suppose that you speak about users ? Then look at the NSS extensions. You may use NIS, LDAP...